# Leaflet Marker - toggle draggable

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet marker created similar to the example below.

```
var marker = L.marker([map.getCenter().lat,map.getCenter().lng], {      
      alt: tempID,
      icon: starIcon,
      draggable: true
  })    
  .addTo(map)
```

I would like to toggle the draggable property. I've tried accessing manually like below to no avail.. Any suggestions?

```
marker.options.draggable=false;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
marker.dragging.disable();
```

and to re-enable:

```
marker.dragging.enable();
```

reference:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-dragging